# can anyone tell me how to get rid of spaces between these two buttons?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, button

[Remove spaces between buttons](https://codepen.io/priyawT/pen/zRdGGo)

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <md-content>
        <section layout="row" layout-phone="column" layout-align="center center">
            <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" md-theme="indigo">Button</md-button>
            <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" md-theme="indigo">Button</md-button> 
        </section>
    </md-content>
</div>
```

Here is the working example with code.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: OP, in your codepen example, right click and inspect the buttons. You'll find a `margin` CSS property that's value is `1em`. If you change that to `.5em` the distance between the buttons decreases. That may be a good place to start

Comment: However, that appears to be external CSS, do you'll have to target and write an overriding style for the margin property here

Comment: Inspect your element (right click inspect element) then you would be able to see `.buttondemoBasicUsage section .md-button` has 1em margin around it.  Remove this and you remove your gap

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of the margin

```css
button{
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the margin from .buttondemoBasicUsage section .md-button as below:

```css
  .buttondemoBasicUsage section .md-button {
    display: block;
    line-height: 25px; 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not the best solution to add `margin: 0` on the whole `button` tag with `!important`. If your project grows you gonna have problems later on. Try to avoid `!important` and use it **only** when you cannot find another solution.

Change `margin: 1em;` in to `margin: 1em 0;` to keep top and bottom and remove right and left margin. To remove whole margin change to `margin: 0;`

```
.buttondemoBasicUsage section .md-button {
        display: block;
        line-height: 25px;
        margin: 1em 0;
    }
```